# FFI / MemoryPointer Memory Allocation

Tags: c++, ruby, windows, ffi

I must be missing something.  I've been reading about FFI and cannot seem to get a clear answer on this.  Let's say I have the following C++ function:

```cpp
extern "C" {
  int ReturnAnArrayOfStrings(const char* arrayOfStrings[]) {
    if( NULL == arrayOfStrings ) return someCharList.size();

    for(auto iter = someCharList.begin(), auto index = 0; iter != someCharList.end(); ++iter, ++index) {
        char* allocatedHere = new char[strlen(*iter)]; // note that this is not freed
        strcpy_s(allocatedHere, strlen(*iter), *iter);
        arrayOfStrings[index] = allocatedHere;
    }

    return someCharList.size();
  }
}
```

From what I can tell, if using this from FFI, all you would have to do is the following:

```rb
module SomeDll
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib 'SomeDll.dll'
  attach_function :get_strings, :ReturnAnArrayOfStrings, [:pointer], :int
end

include SomeDll
pointer = FFI::MemoryPointer.new :pointer, get_strings(nil)  # how many strings are there?
get_strings pointer
pointer.get_array_of_string(0).each do |value|
  puts value
end
```

My question is this:  who cleans up the memory?  The C++ method is `new`'ing  up the char* but never freeing it.  Does FFI handle this?  What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby FFI tries to be symmetric about who owns memory - if you allocate it (i.e. the C code), you have to free it.  Conversely, if FFI allocates it, it alone can free it.

You didn't post your FreeStrings() function, but assuming it looks a bit like:

```
void FreeStringArray(char **strings, int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        delete[] strings[i];
    }
    // Do _NOT_ free 'strings' itself, that is managed by FFI
}
```

And you use it thusly:

```
module SomeDll
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib 'SomeDll.dll'
  attach_function :get_strings, :ReturnAnArrayOfStrings, [:pointer], :int
  attach_function :free_strings, :FreeStringArray, [ :pointer, :int ], :void
end

include SomeDll

count = get_strings(nil)
strings = FFI::MemoryPointer.new :pointer, count
get_strings strings
strings.get_array_of_string(0, count).each do |value|
  puts value
end

# free each element of the array
free_strings(strings, count)
```

Then that should work.

The equivalent C code would be:

```
int count = ReturnArrayOfStrings(NULL);

// Allocate an array for the pointers.  i.e. FFI::MemoryPointer.new :pointer, count
char **ptr_array = (char **) calloc(count, sizeof(char *));

ReturnArrayOfStrings(ptr_array);
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    printf("string[%d]=%s\n", i, ptr_array[i]);
}

// Free each element of the array (but not the array itself)
FreeStringArray(ptr_array, count);

// free the array itself. i.e FFI::MemoryPointer garbage-collecting its  memory
free(ptr_array);
```

Comment: yep, that's exactly what I ended up doing.  Thanks for the clear code explanation!

Answer (score 4):

I think that in many ffi, whichever language you use, values of builtin types (like strings) must be constructed using specially provided runtime functions. Ruby abides to this rule:

See this [article](http://www.eqqon.com/index.php/Ruby_C_Extension_API_Documentation_%28Ruby_1.8%29) for a quick tutorial on that matter, from the language author, for version 1.8 of the language.

If you insist on allocating that data chunk in your code (using C++ or plain C) - after all that's the point of using that extention - the safest path is probably to wrap it with a struct, and use the so called managed struct facility provided by ffi to hook up a dispose function to your data (which you will have to write too), so that ruby knows how to free up the data once it's not needed anymore.
But you can also simply declare your data as a pointer within ruby (it appears that this is what you did), and ask userland to explicitely free that data (again using a dispose function provided by your extention).

Here's [another page](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Examples) demonstrating the use of managed structs.

Lastly, don't forget to qualify any C++ function you wish to export to ruby as `extern "C"` (if you didn't do it already).

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I didn't include the `extern "C"` for brevity, but I will edit the question for clarity.  Thanks again!

Comment: I could be missing something, but I provided the following C method `void FreeStrings(const char* strings[], const int numberOfStrings)`.  I saw no difference (when observing my Working Set in Process Explorer of ruby.exe) between not calling `FreeStrings` from ruby after allocating memory and calling `FreeStrings`.  Or maybe I misunderstood what you said, and since I'm using the `FFI::MemoryPointer` I don't have to worry about it?

Comment: FFI will take care of what it has allocated (space for the requested number of pointers) but knows nothing of the memory allocated by get_strings - you need to be clearing that up